# Sum of 1000 first primes gives wrong output

Tags: c#

i have written a small program to print out the sum of the 1000 first primes, but for some reason i get the wrong result.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long sum;
            sum = 0;
            int count;
            count = 0;

            for (long i = 0; count <= 1000; i++)
            {
                bool isPrime = true;

                for (long j = 2; j < i; j++)
                {
                    if (i != j && i % j == 0)
                    {
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isPrime)
                {
                    sum += i;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}",sum));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

result = **3674995** expected = **3682913**

Comment: Hint: try changing it to find the sum of the first *two* primes, so you can easily debug through it. The problem is pretty simple to fix, but you'll learn a lot more if you work it out for yourself than if we just tell you.

Comment: long i = 0; count <= 1000  means 1001 operations

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev However the summand 0 doesn't hurt.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ofc. that just goes to tell me im shit at logic in the morning. thx i found the problem.

Comment: As an aside, it's generally preferably to initialize variables at the point you declare them: `int count = 0;` and `long sum = 0;`. I'd also personally restructure the loop to be *all* about `count`, and increment `i` on every iteration. A `for` loop where the variable used in the condition isn't the same as the variable used in the iteration part is unusual.

Comment: What exactly makes you believe the desired result is correct?

Comment: Remember not to check j < i but j < sqrt(i) in the second loop for large numbers

Comment: Are you looking for the 1000 first primes or _primes up to 1000_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation is identifying `1` as a prime, which is not correct; this can be fixed by initializing `isPrime` as follows.

```
bool isPrime = i != 1;
```

This yields the desired result 3682913; however the summand of 0 is also taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient implementation checks for just *prime divisors* up to *square root* of the `value`; please, notice that all *even* values are *not* primes (with only exception - `2`):

```
  int count = 1000;

  List<long> primes = new List<long>(count) {
    2 }; // <- the only even prime

  for (long value = 3; primes.Count < count; value += 2) {
    long n = (long) (Math.Sqrt(value) + 0.1);

    foreach (var divisor in primes)
      if (divisor > n) {
        primes.Add(value);

        break;
      }
      else if (value % divisor == 0)
        break;
  }

  // 3682913
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", primes.Sum()));
  Console.ReadLine();
```

Try `count = 1000000` and you'll get `7472966967499`

Answer (score -1):

```
            long sum;
            sum = 0;
            int count;
            count = 0;

            for (long i = 0; count <= 1000; i++)
            {
                if (i == 1) continue;
                bool isPrime = true;

                for (long j = 2; j < i; j++)
                {
                    if (i != j && i % j == 0)
                    {
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isPrime)
                {
                    sum += i;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", sum));
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This doesn't explain much. Yes, it gives the correct result, but due to two errors that cancel out: counting 0 as a prime and summing over the first 1001 'primes'. I'd rather do `for (long i = 2; count < 1000; ++i)`.